# Meta box in links / Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, bookmarks

Is there a way to save meta box value when it's added to links?
Here is my code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Link Date
Plugin URI: http://
Description: Adds links date field.
Version: None
Author: Auth
Author URI: http://
*/

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'link_date_add' );
function link_date_add()
{
    add_meta_box( 'link-date-meta-box', 'Link Date', 'link_date', 'link', 'normal', 'high'     );
    }


function link_date( $post )
{
    $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
    $date = isset( $values['link_date_text'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['link_date_text'][0] ) : '';
    wp_nonce_field( 'my_link_date_nonce', 'link_date_nonce' );
    var_dump($post);
    ?>
<p>
    <label for="link_date_text">Link Date</label>
    <input type="text" name="link_date_text" id="link_date_text" value="<?php echo $date; ?>" />
</p>

<?php
}


add_action( 'save_post', 'link_date_save' );
function link_date_save( $post_id )
{
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

    if( !isset( $_POST['link_date_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['link_date_nonce'], 'my_link_date_nonce' ) ) return;

    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;

    $allowed = array(
        'a' => array(
        'href' => array() // and those anchords can only have href attribute
    )
);


if( isset( $_POST['link_date_text'] ) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'link_date_text', wp_kses( $_POST['link_date_text'], $allowed ) );


}

?>
```

This code works, when post type changed to 'post', but for some reason it doesn't save data as 'link' type of post.

I saved some data from this field when post type was set as 'post', then updated the post type in code to  'link', and additionally updated the database (wp_postmeta) replacing the id with the id of link. Then this data was displayed in meta box  in links, but still, bot able to update value of this metabox.

Comment: why do need a plugin why not use custom fields?

Comment: so use this [example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box#Example) and change `$screens = array( 'post', 'page' );` to `$screens = array('link' );`

Comment: did you tested? I'm not able to save the data.

Comment: Yes I tested and the example worked

Comment: would you mind sharing the working example, I'm having hard time to make it work.

Comment: did you try this http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box#Example one?

Comment: YEs, but not 'within the class'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25567/discussion-between-david-chase-and-user1354499)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use `add_action('edit_link','save_data')` and `add_option('name_of_option')` instead of `add_post_meta` view full results here [MetaBox Links](https://gist.github.com/davidchase/df9adeb1e03b88691899)

Comment: @user1354499 thank you for being patient and glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

After some experiments, I figured out how to save data from custom metabox in link manager into db as post meta key/value (wp_postmeta).
If someone needs, here is a working example:

```
action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_link_date' );
function add_link_date()
{
    add_meta_box( 'link-date-meta-box', 'Link Date', 'link_date', 'link', 'normal', 'high' );
}

function link_date( $link )
{
    $values = get_post_custom( $link->link_id );
    $date = isset( $values['link_date'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['link_date'][0] ) : '';
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'link_date_nonce' );
?>
<p>
    <label for="link_date_text">Link Date</label>
    <input type="text" name="link_date_text" id="link_date_text" value="<?php echo $date; ?>" />
</p>

<?php
}


add_action( 'edit_link', 'myplugin_save_postdata' );

function myplugin_save_postdata( ) {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return;

    if ( !isset( $_POST['link_date_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['link_date_nonce'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
        return;

    $link_id = $_POST['link_id'];
    $linkDate = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['link_date_text'] );

    add_post_meta( $link_id, 'link_date', $linkDate, true ) or
    update_post_meta( $link_id, 'link_date', $linkDate );
}
```